# What is the recommended way to analyze my document fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following structure of documents in my index:

```
{
  firstName: "A",
  lastName: "b",
  title: "CEO",
  phone: "1900900900",
  department: "Product"
}
```

I wonder what is the best way to analyze and tokenize this document, so I can perform searches on that documents( case insensitive). the searches are done by end users through a web site.

So What I did is to set the following mapping:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "lowercase": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
         }
       }
     },
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "dynamic_templates": [{
             "field_unanalyzed": {
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "mapping": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "lowercase"
                }
             }
          }
      ]
}}}
```

When performing the search I lowercase the query and then run the search query.
So for example if the user queries the firstname field, with "a" or "A" the search should return the document above.

Does it make sense?
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So far, it makes sense. But the best way to find out is to try some queries and see if that returns the documents you expect. The only thing that could itch a bit is when searching by phone, people usually know only a prefix of the phone number and not necessarily the whole number.

Comment: It looks working, my problem is that I need to remember (or the next developer) to lower case the value that is received by the client, for the query to return results.

Comment: You could also specify a `search_analyzer` that does the lowercasing for you and since you've specified `analyzer: lowercase` that should already be the case.